# Merging Features

Tags: pyqgis, merge

I want to merge features of a vector layer into one single feature using the python console.
Somewhere I found the following solution. However it does not seem to work for me. When I execute the following code in the python console

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
geoms = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY')
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
  geoms = geoms.combine(feature.geometry())
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'combine'
```

What went wrong ? Or how to do it differently with python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change line 2 to:

```
geoms = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION()')
```

Then it works, even this version is not conform to Wkt spec, as is your's.