# problem combining geometries from all features in a layer as one geometry

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, pyqgis, merge

I am trying to combine all features of a Polygon layer in QGIS in a python plugin, and am running into this error when I try to run the combine method:

"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'combine'
Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.10.1-Pisa Pisa, d20c5b7"

I've looked at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59126/how-to-merge-selected-features-with-python) before but am not sure what I am doing incorrectly:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QFileDialog
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources, processing
# Import the code for the dialog
from save_attributes_dialog import SaveAttributesDialog
import os.path
```

Here is my code for the run method:

```
def run(self):
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:

        selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
        selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]

        features = selectedLayer.getFeatures()
        geoms = QgsGeometry()

        for feature in features:
            geoms = geoms.combine(feature.geometry())
```

I ran the loop just printing out the areas of each feature before which worked fine, so I'm guessing it is able to access the features without a problem, but am not sure what to do about the NoneType issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detlev, after looking at one of [your other posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176235/merging-features) I realized I just needed to initialize the empty geometry object as:

```
geoms = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION()')
```

The information about validating geometries will be useful for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

At least one of the polygon features has no or invalid geometry. You can provoke this error as follows:

```
geoms = QgsGeometry()
g1 = QgsGeometry()
geoms = geoms.combine(g1)
# no problem, despite empty geometry

geoms = geoms.combine(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'combine'
```

I suggest some consistency check before calling `combine` like this:

```
geoms = geometry()
for feature in features:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    if geom:
        err = geom.validateGeometry()
        if not err:
            geoms = geoms.combine(geom)
        else:
            print '%d geometry errors detected (feature %d)' % (len(err), feature.id())
```

Comment: After implementing the check for consistency I am getting the same error at the combine method: 
'geoms = geoms.combine(geom)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'combine''

I tested it on another shapefile also and gave the same results.

Comment: Ok, then I guess that there are polygons with holes (donut). I just tested some some simple polygons and a donut. And when it comes to the donut the error occures.