# Creating feature from multiple LineStrings using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geometry, features, polyline-creation

I am trying to create a closed LineString made of a number of CircularSrings, but have got stuck.  I cannot see how to add the geometry from both strings.

This is what I have so far. QGIS version 3.4.2

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "temp", "memory")

pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String)])
vl.updateFields() 
cString1 = QgsCircularString.fromTwoPointsAndCenter(QgsPoint(306580,167317),QgsPoint(306680,167317),QgsPoint(306680,167217))
cString2 = QgsCircularString.fromTwoPointsAndCenter(QgsPoint(306680,167317),QgsPoint(306580,167317),QgsPoint(306680,167417))

geom_cString1 = QgsGeometry(cString1)
geom_cString2 = QgsGeometry(cString2)
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(geom_cString1)
f.setAttributes(["One"])
pr.addFeature(f)
vl.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Answer provided on this post to combine two geometries https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/176237/143973

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Static `collectGeometry` method of `QgsGeometry` class performs what you need.

```
...
geom_cString1=QgsGeometry(cString1)
geom_cString2=QgsGeometry(cString2)

geom = QgsGeometry().collectGeometry([geom_cString1, geom_cString2])

f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(geom)
...
```

The closed ring in the image is one LineString geometry.

[image]